# Force ionic app to use only on desktop platform

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to force my ionic app (5.3.5) to desktop plateform

because, there are tablet pc in my company, and plateform returns "mobile+tablet" for those computers.
example: I want allways "plt-desktop" class instead of "plt-mobile , plt-tablet" in < html > tag for this app.

thank for your help.

Comment: Use Electronjs .

Comment: I think that's not possible in Ionic... May I ask why do you need to do that? – Maybe there's a better way to handle your requirements? :)